# Signing in with user-name instead of email

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I've created a new Web Forms Project in visual studio 2013 and I want users to be able to login using their UserName(eg. administrator) not their email address.

If you open the automatically generated "Register.aspx.cs" file you'll see this piece of code:

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
```

**Question:**
Why does the UserName and Email have the same value on last line??? In this case why do you need UserName column since you have already Email column?

---

### **Is possible to login using username not email address?**

---

I'm trying to solve this by adding a new textbox field to registration form called "UserName":

> Register.aspx

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">UserName</asp:Label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
            CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The UserName field is required." />
    </div>
</div>
```

And on the Register function I've made this change:

> Register.aspx.cs

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text, Email = Email.Text };
```

---

Then I've changed the login function like this:

> Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user password
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                //var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, false, shouldLockout: false);

                SignInStatus result = SignInStatus.Failure;

                // check too see if the user has entered a email address or not
                if (IsValidEmail(NameOrEmail.Text))
                {
                    result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(NameOrEmail.Text, Password.Text, false, shouldLockout: false);
                }
                else
                {
                    // get users email using his name
                    var user = manager.FindByName(NameOrEmail.Text);

                    result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(user.Email, Password.Text, false, shouldLockout: false);
                }


                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        string queryString = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
                            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        else
                            Response.Redirect("/Account/Dashboard");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureTextLabel.Text = "Invalid login!";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // check email address
        private bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
        {
            // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
            return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
        }
```

And the template looks like this:

> Login.aspx

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NameOrEmail" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">UserName or Email</asp:Label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="NameOrEmail"
            CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The name or email field is required." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem:**
If you change the UserName on Register you cannot login anymore(you'll get SignInStatus.Failure). 
Seems to me that the UserName has to be the same as Email on registration for the login to work.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this isn't a bug at all. This is how it works, if you want to use out of the box default implementation which created with the **visual studio 2013 template** (with individual users) then you will get it that way.

As developers asp.net identity stuff can be configurable according to our choice. For that you need to go deep into identity framework and understand how it works.

Most of simple yet very important configuration can be found in the **IdentityConfig.cs** file if you have used v**isual studio 2013 with update 3** or later.

identity framework version 1 comes with only with username without email address supporting UI, but things changed with the **version 2.x and visual studio 2013 update 3 and 4** which included email address for both username and email.

You can change it to use username instead email as explained below.

New out of the box registration code is:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

You can see that the Username and Email both uses model.Email.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

**Update your code as below**

*Register method*

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
            {
                RequireUniqueEmail = false,
            };

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

*RegisterViewModel*

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

*LoginViewModel*

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Further you need to update other view models not to use email and instead use username

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Then update all views to use UserName instead Email like below.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I've already run through that piece of code that you've posted. That code is for MVC and I said that I'm using Web Forms.

Comment: Actually i did answered this for your first question title, then updated according to your new title, but forgot about web forms. The logic is same, just need to change the forms to use username instead email.

Comment: Is not quite the same, in Web Forms project you don't have LoginViewModel or RegisterViewModel. In my example the login function is "signinManager.PasswordSignIn()" which needs the user email address. If I manually change the username in database, the login will not work anymore even if I use the email address.